# Django and Yubikey integrate

Tags: python, django, two-factor-authentication, yubico

I want to integrate Yubikey with my Django application.  Whenever I try to add a 2FA Yubikey: `localhost:8080/account/two_factor/setup/` I get a `403 HTTP Forbidden` error. How do I implement the Yubikey in Django, because when I use these tutorials then the implementation fails.

When I follow the example [here](http://example-two-factor-auth.herokuapp.com/) to do the same I get a `Server Error 500`

I followed these tutoriols:

- [django-two-factor-auth](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/1.12.1/installation.html#yubikey-setup)
- [django-otp-yubikey](https://django-otp-yubikey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [djangp-otp](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

This is what I have done:

```
pip install django-two-factor-auth
pip install django-otp-yubikey
pip install django-otp
```

I use Python 3.7.3 and Django 3.0.8

In my `settings.py` I added:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # OTP
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'two_factor',
    'otp_yubikey',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
    ...
]

LOGIN_URL = 'two_factor:login'

TWO_FACTOR_PATCH_ADMIN = True
```

In my `urls.py` I added:

```
from two_factor.urls import urlpatterns as tf_urls
from django_otp.views import LoginView
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    # OTP
    path('', include(tf_urls)),
    ...
]
```

And in my `views.py` I have added:

```
from django_otp.decorators import otp_required

@otp_required
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'result': 'test')
```

My `home.html` is simple:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><p>test</p></body>
</html>
```

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR 2020-07-20 14:14:24,571 log 35773 123145342668800 Internal Server Error: /account/two_factor/setup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py", line 244, in dispatch
response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/two_factor/views/utils.py", line 156, in post
return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py", line 294, in post
if form.is_valid():
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in is_valid
return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
self.full_clean()
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 376, in full_clean
self._clean_fields()
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 397, in _clean_fields
value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/two_factor/forms.py", line 84, in clean_token
return super().clean_token()
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/two_factor/forms.py", line 70, in clean_token
if not self.device.verify_token(token):
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/otp_yubikey/models.py", line 280, in verify_token
response = client.verify(token)
File "/Users/user_anon/work_folder/home_dir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yubiotp/client.py", line 48, in verify
stream = urlopen(url)
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh, Ok so I edited the `client.py` in `yubiotp` so have full control over the URL that is used in `urlopen`

replaced

```
stream = urlopen(url)
```

with

```
from app import views as v_yow
...
stream = v_yow.test(url)
```

The `views.py`:

```
from six.moves import xrange
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlencode
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

import urllib


def test(url):
    """
    """
    print('Testing 123')
    print(url)
    url_without_http = url[4:]
    url_with_https = 'https' + url_without_http

    stream = urlopen(url_with_https)
    return stream
```

And this works excellent. So the problem here is that the requested URL was a HTTP url and not a HTTPS url. The HTTP url redirects to HTTPS but fails to word in the lib `urlopen(url)`.

So to make this work without having this weird "fix" make sure you set the  `use_ssl` to `True` in :

```
classotp_yubikey.models.ValidationService(*args, **kwargs)[source]
```